# Sublime 3 scroll_past_end set number of lines it will scroll past

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

Is there a way to set the maximum number of lines it will scroll past? For example I want the last line to remain roughly at the middle of the editor window. Thanks!

for example, with `'scroll_past_end': false,`

```
560 lorem ipsum
561 lorem ipsum
562 lorem ipsum
563 lorem ipsum
564 lorem ipsum
565 lorem ipsum
566 lorem ipsum
567 lorem ipsum
568 lorem ipsum
569 lorem ipsum
570 lorem ipsum
```

with `'scroll_past_end': true,`

```
570 lorem ipsum
```

this is what I want

```
566 lorem ipsum
567 lorem ipsum
568 lorem ipsum
569 lorem ipsum
570 lorem ipsum
```

Answer (score 3):

Your question is tagged `sublimetext3`; in ST3, it's not possible to change this behaviour (other than to turn it off entirely).

In Sublime Text 4, the `scroll_past_end` setting is enhanced to allow you to specify how much of a scroll should happen. It's based a percentage of the visible content and not a number of lines, but you could set it to for example `0.8` or `0.9` to allow for a few lines of context at the top rather than just one.

```json
    // Set to false to disable scrolling past the end of the buffer.
    // On Mac, this value is overridden in the platform specific settings, so
    // you'll need to place this line in your user settings to override it.
    //
    // This setting may also be set to a number between 0.0 and 1.0 to specify
    // how much scrolling past the end of the buffer should be allowed. 0.5
    // scrolls halfway and 0.0 is the same as false.
    "scroll_past_end": true,
```

Answer (score 1):

As @OdatNurd explained, "scroll_past_end" can be set to a float value in the range [0.0, 1.0]. In your case, @mightbesimon, you can achieve your desired view with:

```
{
    ...

    "scroll_past_end": 0.5,
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer - Should get more votes !